# Scraping a webpage for state name

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping

I am working on a little project that searches a set of web pages for some PII. In particular, I am having some difficulty in correctly scraping the page to extract the State the person lives in. The specific example that wreaks havoc is Indiana. My regex searches each page for the presence of a full state name or a state abbreviation. In this case, there are a LOT of false positives being returned since the abbreviation for Indiana is IN. So my case insensitive search is literally returning every web page since 'in' is such a common word. Is there any clever regex or other technique i can use to eliminate this hiccup? I can try matching the state by looking for a comma followed by the abbreviation but sometimes web pages dont include the comma (ie. ', IN'). Any ideas?

This is my regex fyi. It looks up the state fullname and the abbreviation for that state as returned by a key-value pair returned from a function call:

```
re.search(r'\b{0}\b|\b{1}\b'.format(state.strip(), stateDictionaryLookup(state.strip())), webpage, re.IGNORECASE)
```

Comment: FYI, it's spelled `Indiana`, in case that was throwing you...

Comment: apologies, spell check didnt pick that up here.

Comment: Why are you using a case insensitive search since the abbreviation is IN not in?  Would that help.  Is there something else you can anchor on - for example a zipcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no perfect way to easily do this that I know of. What you should do depends on the ratio of false positives to false negatives you want.

Here are a few observations that may help:

- The state abbreviation IN is preceded or followed by `,`, `;`, or `.` more often than the word in.
- The word in is almost never preceded *and* followed by `,`, `;`, or `.`, whereas it should not be uncommon to find the abbreviation preceded and followed by `,`, `;`, or `.`.
- The word in is rarely written as IN, but the abbreviation IN is almost always uppercase.